# importing usestate in nextjs14 giving me error as cannot read propertities of undefined ('products')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, next.js, deployment

`

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
slug: String,
img: String,
details: String,
availableQty: Number,
variants: String,
price: Number,
color: String,
size: String,
category: String
},);

const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

export default Product;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.